# Are the projective transformations between two planes Möbius Transformations?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Given two planes(infinity included) and one point as centre of projection, there is a transformation between the planes geometrically; regard the two planes as complex planes, is the former transformation a Möbius one? Further, is every Möbius transformation also a projective one as described before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is easy to see once you realize that projective transformations in $\mathbb{P}^n$ are given by linear transformations in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ by thinking of projective space as the subspace of points where the $n+1$-st coordinate equals $1$ (plus the stuff at infinity).

It's not clear to me exactly what definition you are using but from what I can see it looks like you can simply write down the formula for your transformations and observe that they are given by linear maps as above, and that all linear maps can be obtained.

Once you specialize the observation in the first paragraph to the case $n=1$ one easily gets the formula $x \mapsto \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, since a linear map in $\mathbb{C}^2$ has the form $(x,y) \mapsto (ax+by, cx+dy)$, and this latter point is projected to the representative $(\frac{ax+by}{cx+dy}, 1)$, and restricting $(x,y)$ to the set of representatives (ie. letting $y=1$) gives the maps $(x,1)\mapsto (\frac{ax+b}{cx+d},1)$.

Comment: Another nice thing with this definition is that the fact that a Möbius transformation is given by its value at three points not on a line becomes equivalent to the fact that a linear mapping in three-dimensional space is determined by the values on three linearly independent vectors.